# joining a small table significantly slows down a query

Tags: sql-server, sorting, join, sql-server-2008-r2

**Problem:** Joining a relatively small table into a query with many joins doubles the execution time of a query.

**Challenge:** How could query or data structures be optimized so that the query executes much faster?

There are indexes everywhere, and statistics are actual.

3 passes, measured with SQL Server Profiler:

- Without extra join: avg **3741ms**
- With extra join: avg **6733ms** - this is **+80%**

Basically, the query is about filtering and aggregating values from a large budget table.

- Table `budget`contains around 700,000 records
- For filtering, we have tables `f1`,`f2`,`f3` which contain values selected by user. These filter tables have 1 to max. 70 records
- For aggregating, we have tables `a1`,`a2`,`a3` which are used for aggregating the dimensions to group aggregates.
- Budget Table: 700,000 records
- Final Result: 2,400 records

**Original query:**

```
select a1.agg1, a2.agg2, a3.agg3, sum(b.value)
from 
     budget b  -- 700.000 records
     inner join f1 on b.dim1 = f1.dim1  
     inner join f2 on b.dim2 = f2.dim2   
     inner join f3 on b.dim3 = f3.dim3   
     inner join a1 on b.dim1 = a1.dim1   
     inner join a2 on b.dim2 = a2.dim2
     inner join a3 on b.dim3 = a3.dim3
group by a1.agg1, a2.agg2, a3.agg3
order by a1.agg1, a2.agg2, a3.agg3
```

Now I'm adding the left join. It brings in an additional count of an extra table which holds comments to some figures.

So this join adds a column in the result, but does not change the rows.

The table `comments` only has around 1,500 records.

**New query:**

```
select a1.agg1, a2.agg2, a3.agg3, sum(b.value), count(c.CommentText) as commentcount
from 
     budget b  -- 700.000 records
     inner join f1 on b.dim1 = f1.dim1  
     inner join f2 on b.dim2 = f2.dim2   
     inner join f3 on b.dim3 = f3.dim3   
     inner join a1 on b.dim1 = a1.dim1   
     inner join a2 on b.dim2 = a2.dim2
     inner join a3 on b.dim3 = a3.dim3
     left join comments c on b.dim1= c.dim1 and b.dim2=c.dim2 and b.dim3=c.dim3
group by a1.agg1, a2.agg2, a3.agg3
order by a1.agg1, a2.agg2, a3.agg3
```

I compared the execution plans of both queries in detail. The extra left join leads to 3 extra operations with the following costs:

- Clustered Index scan (on the joined table): 1%
- Merge Join (left outer join): 10%
- Sort: 13%

The Sort is an extra sort which appears only with the join. With extra join, I have two sorts (one before and one after the merge join), otherwise only one sort.

Interestingly, the costs are not really matching with reality. But anyway. The basic question is: How could that be improved? Any ideas?

Comment: Your set is too complex for me to create the testing data. But I find that very often you can significantly boost the performance of scenarios like this one, by either using CROSS / OUTER APPLY, or doing the query in smaller batches, for  instance saving a mid batch in a temp table and using that for the second half of the operation.

In this case, just check for fun what happens when you replace stuff as follows: LEFT JOIN ... -> OUTER APPLY (SELECT count(*) cCnt from comments c where b.dim1= c.dim1 and b.dim2=c.dim2 and b.dim3=c.dim3) C, .. and count(c.CommentText) -> sum(C.cCnt) ?

Comment: In general. Choosing between "joins first and then one big grouping" and "many little groupings first and then joins of aggregated data", I personally prefer the second approach. For my experience it works much faster.

Comment: @Kahn - thank you for guiding me to the `apply`operator. That's an interesting approach for investigation. I tried your hint: well, it improved only a little bit, the average (3 passes) now went down from 6743ms to 6553ms. Although that's not much, there is at least now some approach. The execution plans looks different now. I'm further investigating.

Comment: @Kahn I tried a `CROSS APPLY` instead of `OUTER APPLY`, and now the average indeed goes down from 6844ms to 4848ms ! I read up about the `apply` operator, and when I understand it right, then in this case, `cross apply`and `outer apply` should result into the same, because `select count(*) ... ` **always** produces a record.

Comment: @Kahn the `APPLY` operator was a great hint. I now even tried to rewrite the whole query and put the calculation of the sums (those with the big table) on the right side of an `cross apply`, with a filter at a later stage, and I couldn't believe it: **query is now 4 times faster!!** I had not expected that, still cannot really understand why it is so fast now, and the execution plans looks horrible big & crammed ;) I checked it very thoroughly, there is for sure no flaw, the result is the same.